# "Publish Android App" in Visual Studio 2015 RC with Apache Cordova is not doing anything

Tags: android, cordova, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

I am attempting to create an Android app using the Visual Studio 2015 RC with Apache Cordova (a multi-platform hybrid app) and for some reason, when I go to:

TOOLS -> ANDROID -> PUBLISH ANDROID APP...

I get a quick thinking/circling mouse pointer then nothing.

Useful Information:

-The installation went fine and I can use the Ripple emulator fine.
-I did the same steps on a machine with Comodo which allowed me to see what Visual Studio was attempting to access and it was definitely reaching out to the Java tools on the computer (I assume to build the apk).

Other than that, I have no idea! :) Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for using Visual Studio tools for Apache Cordova.

I presume you are using the following menu, which is added to Visual Studio by the [Xamarin Tools](https://www.visualstudio.com/explore/xamarin-vs) and can be used only with Xamarin and not with Tools for Apache Cordova. 
[image]

To publish an hybrid android app to Google play store, using Tools for Apache Cordova, you will have to follow manual steps which are provided [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/cordova-docs/tree/master/tutorial-package-publish#android)

I agree that showing this menu for tools for Apache Cordova is confusing and leading users to believe this is a supported scenario. I will take this observation/feedback with the product team and let them know.

Once again, thanks for using our tools.

Comment: Thank you so much. It's not too confusing once you know where to look. For some reason I am getting a "Describe Error - There is a problem parsing the package." error when I attempt to actually install the app. Do you know any sort of common reason for that? Thank you.

Comment: Hey Pickel, when do you get the error? Is it when VS tries to install the app onto the device as part of its Run process? Would love to hear more about this error.

Comment: I completely forgot to update this and I am so sorry, I know you need user feedback so please accept my apology. I was not getting an error per se, just a quick circle then nothing. I was able to build an APK with the instructions you sent though